# What does "divorce from affair" and "divorce from marriage" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

> divorces, from affairs as well as marriages, could take unexpected
>   bitter turns.

Divorce means "..., their marriage is legally ended."
A and B are in affair (They haven't legally married), then the parted. Can this be called divorce? (I think cann't)

And what does 'take bitter turns' mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. Words in English often evolve over time such that the words get used in less specific situations. Then, if that newly-coined usage becomes widespread enough, that meaning will eventually make its way into dictionaries also, as the dictionaries catch up with the vernacular.

When I look up the word *divorce* on [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/divorce), for example, the first definition I see matches the one you gave:

> **divorce** (*n.*) The legal dissolution of a marriage.

However, the second definition listed is one that would indicate that A and B could also be "divorced" from an affair, particularly if the affair had been lasting for some time:

> **divorce** (*n.*) A complete or radical severance of closely connected things.

Other, more-general definitions from Wordnik include:

- separation; disunion of things closely united.
- part; cease or break association with

As for *bitter turns*, you've committed a [cardinal sin](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/cardinal_sin) on ELL by [not telling us where you found this quote](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source), so I'd have to speculate a little bit. But, generally speaking, if something like a breakup takes a "bitter turn," we can assume that it didn't go as smoothly as expected.